# Insert node - memory leak in C

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, linked-list

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE {
    int data;
    struct NODE *next;
} node;

typedef struct {
    node *head;
} list;

void insert_node_at(list *lst, int index, int data) {
    node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    n->data = data;
    n->next = NULL;
    node *back = lst->head;

    if (!lst->head) {
        n->next = n;
        lst->head = n;
    } else if (index == 0) {
        while (back->next != lst->head) {
            back = back->next;
        }
        back->next = n;
        n->next = lst->head;
        lst->head = n;
    } else {
        while (back->next != lst->head && index > 0) {
            back = back->next;
            index--;
        }
        n->next = back->next;
        back->next = n;
    }
}
```

This is the code to insert a node at some index in a circular linked list, where the last node points to the first node(at index=0).

Beginner in C, I have been trying for hours to figure out why this function causes **memory leaks when running `valgrind`**, even though it gives the correct ouput. I tried to use as few variables as possible in the code. Since the new node is a required part of the new list, not sure how I would free the allocated space?

thank you

Comment: valgrind will report memory leaks if you don't free the entire list at the end of the program.

Comment: I free the list in the main method at the end. When I run valgrind, it says that the leak is caused by this method only.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. `valgrind` will report the function that allocates memory, not the function that is supposed to free the memory but doesn't.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to free the memory when deleting nodes